# Is `10e1` an Integer literal or Floating point literal?

Tags: javascript, literals

I was looking into [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Integers) and wondering if `10e1` is an Integer Literal or a Floating Point Literal.

I know that `100` is an Integer literal. Does it make any difference if I write `10e1` instead?

When I check in the [spec here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#prod-DecimalLiteral)(7) or [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/index.html#sec-7.8.3)(5.1), there is nothing called "Floating Point Literal". Is this just another incorrect doc in MDN? Any idea what Floating Point Literal refers to?

To summarise:

1. Does `100` and `10e1` fall into same category of literals? If yes, which?
2. Is there something called "Floating Point Literal"?

Comment: Does it make a difference in Javascript? It only has a single number data type (which is 64 bit floating point)

Comment: @Thilo It can make a huge difference for a JIT compiler of javascript

Comment: Javascript just has type number, although saying that there are tricks to make the compiler think in integer ways.

Comment: From looking at the spec `10e1` is a decimal integer literal with an optional exponent. --- Also, I thought all numbers in js were 64bit floating point...? We should remember, the spec is for ECMAScript engine implementors, not users.

Comment: @Thilo - wrong, it's 64bit floating point

Comment: @evolutionxbox That summarises that `10e1` is Decimal Literal?

Comment: In Chrome's developer console`10e1.constructor.name` returns `"Number"`

Comment: @phuzi Every number returns that. There's only one number data type. That's not the question.

Comment: I think that document is talking about how you express numbers, like mentioned in javascript there is only 1 number type.  But when it comes to expressing that number, been floating point & integer does have a different meaning. eg.  Try expressing a floating point Octal, and it will fail, so this is an integer literal only.. IOW:  0o123 fine, 0o123.123 as it's not an integer literal.

Comment: @Thilo *Does it make any difference?* is a part of the question. As in memory allocated or Range of values or arithmetic. From a dev perspective obviously this is the only concern!

Comment: "As in memory allocated or Range of values or arithmetic. From a dev perspective obviously this is the only concern!"  Well, then there is no difference. There is only a single type Number and your literal will end up as that.

Comment: @JJJ Both these `literals` refer to the same value, `100`.  Yeah, there shouldn't be any difference! Yes.

Comment: >>  Is this just another incorrect doc in MDN?    No as there talking about literals, and not types.  From a dev's perspective it is important from the point of view of knowing you can't say create an octal floating point.

Comment: I just made some performance tests in Firefox 51. It seems that in loops, `10e1` and similar literals perform essentially identical to integers (comparable to `100` and `100|0`) which are about twice as fast as floating point literals.

Comment: There shouldn't be any difference in [internal representation](http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754/) either. Only possible difference should be in lex/parse.

Comment: @Keith But how can they come up with a literal (Floating-point Literal) that is not there in Language Specification?

Comment: @sabithpocker  Not sure what you mean, 10.001, is a floating point literal,  0o123 is an integer literal.  Just because the language doesn't have a type for integer, doesn't mean an integer literal / floating point literal cannot be expressed.  IOW: There is no integer type in javascript, but there is an integer literal, the two things are talking about 2 different things.  If that makes sense.. :)

Comment: @Keith Yes, that sounds fine. To explain myself floating point literals are rather classified as Decimal Literal. While there is Decimal Integer Literal, there is no DecimalFloatingPoint literal. That is what I meant by "there is no floating point literal". There is "OctalIntegerLiteral" in latest spec. for `0o123`.

Comment: @Xufox,  javascript JIT's are rather good at detecting implicit integer's.  So if an integer can be implied, there is a performance boost.  eg. I've just done some performance tests, and doing integer increment's 'v' floating point.  integer = 0.888ms,  floating point = 2.316ms.. The code was identical apart from one thing, the loop incrementer was l+=1.00000000001, so the number of loops was the same, but performance was massively different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it make any difference if I write `10e1` instead of `100`?

Not for the result, no. But it's one character more to transfer and parse (so better use `1e2` :-D), and it will affect readability. Not everyone is familiar with exponents.

> In the spec there is nothing called "Floating Point Literal". Is this just another incorrect doc in MDN?

The MDN guide is dubious for sure, naming a sections "Integers" in an article about JS types is confusing at least.

> Does `100` and `10e1` fall into same category of literals? If yes, which?

Yes, they're both numeric literals. JS does not distinguish between numbers with and without a fractional part, they all have the same floating-point type. There is only one grammar for decimal number literals, with fractional digits and exponents being optional.

> Any idea what Floating Point Literal refers to?

It's meant as "(number) literal for a floating-point number", just as "Integer literal" means "(number) literal for a floating-point number representing an integer".

Comment: That sounds like the answer that I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalLiteral::
    DecimalIntegerLiteral.DecimalDigits(opt) ExponentPart(opt)
    .DecimalDigits ExponentPart(opt)
    DecimalIntegerLiteral ExponentPart(opt)
DecimalIntegerLiteral::
    0
    NonZeroDigitDecimalDigitsopt
```

As per spec, `100` and `10e1` are both "DecimalLiteral" while `100` also qualifies to be "DecimalIntegerLiteral"

None of these should make any real difference to the developer as mentioned in comments by [@Thilo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14955/thilo)

The internal representation as per IEEE-754 should as well be the same.

```
Status  Sign [1]    Exponent [11]      Significand [52]
Normal  0 (+)       10000000101 (+6)   1.1001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 (1.5625)
```